# Adapter pattern in Node.js, functional style

Tags: javascript, node.js, design-patterns, functional-programming, adapter

I'm converting GoF patterns to a functional style in Node.js to improve my understanding and increase a flexibility of a code.

Here is an Adapter pattern as I see it regarding to using different DBs without changing a client code.

Below you can see the client code and the different adapters.
I'm adapting MongoDB & Redis drivers' interfaces to a generic DB interface shown in the end.

Fake MongoDB adapter works well, other not tested.

**The question:** Is my understanding of the Adapter pattern right? And from a functional style view point?

[View at GitHub](https://github.com/dibikhin/nodejs-func-patterns/tree/master/adapter_db)

*server.js, Entry point:*

```
    var fake_mongodb_adapter = require('./fake_mongodb_adapter');
    var app = require('./app');

    app.run(fake_mongodb_adapter);
```

*app.js:*

```
    module.exports = {
        run: run
    };

    function run(db) {
        db.connect('something');

        db.get({ id: '1234' }, function (err, found_person) {
            console.log('found person: ' + JSON.stringify(found_person));
        });
    }
```

*mongodb_adapter.js:*

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose'); // Adaptee
    var Person;

    module.exports = {
        connect: connect,
        get: get
    };

    function connect(options) {
        mongoose.connect(options);

        Person = mongoose.model('Person', {
            name: String,
            age: Number
        });
    }

    function get(query, callback) {
        var mongo_query = { _id: query.id };
        return Person.find(mongo_query).exec(callback);
    }
```

*redis_adapter.js:*

```
    var redis = require('redis'); // Adaptee
    var client;

    module.exports = {
        connect: connect,
        get: get
    };

    function connect(options) {
        client = redis.createClient(options);
        client.on('error', function (err) {
            console.log('Error ' + err);
        });
    }

    function get(query, callback) {
        client.get(query.id, function (err, reply) {
            console.log(reply);
            return callback(null, reply);
        });
    }
```

*fake_mongodb_adapter.js:*

```
    var person = {
        id: '1234',
        name: 'Mary',
        age: 21
    };

    module.exports = {
        connect: connect,
        get: get
    };

    function connect(options) {
        console.log('connected to fake MongoDB adapter');
    }

    function get(query, callback) {
        return callback(null, person);
    }
```

*db.js, Interface expected by a client:*

```
    db.connect(options)

    db.get(query, callback)
```

Comment: I don't see anything functional in that code.

Comment: @Bergi it is built around modules with functions' set and not with classes and objects' instantiation. And how do you see it in the functional manner?

Comment: Yes you instantiated objects, with those object literals, to use them as singletons. However, object-orientation is definitely not a bad thing, and completely ortogonal to functional programming. The [functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) paradigm is much about purity and immutability, which you have violated hard in your `connect` methods.

Comment: @Bergi thx. Do you think that the clients should be passed to `connect` and other functions in each call? Like this `function connect(client, ...) { ... }`.